# Mongoose Schema: making an object within an array have a unique field for the document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am **not** trying to make a unique array element, but rather ensure that if I have an array of `pairs` (which are objects) all have a different value for `code`.

Here is my schema's definition:

```
const redirectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    default_link: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    pairs: [
        {
            code: { // I want this field specifically to be unique within the document only
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            site: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }

        }
    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
```

So for example, inserting a `pair` like so is OK.

```
{
    code: "US",
    site: "google.com"
}
```

But inserting another `pair` with the same `code` within this document should NOT be okay, regardless of the `site`.

```
{
    code: "US", // Should not work, since the code "US" already exists within the array of pairs
    site: "amazon.com"
}
```

I'm trying to do this using `Redirect.findOne()` and `Redirect.updateOne()` but I've either been getting compiler errors or the check will only be performed after a duplicate is already present.

Here's my route so far (allows duplicate `code`s):

```
// Add pair to given redirect
router.post('/:name/insert_pair', verifyToken, async (request, response) => {
    const token = request.header("auth-token")
    const usernameFromToken = jwt.decode(token).username

    const { code, site } = request.body

    // Remember: you may edit only your own content
    try {
        const edited = await Redirect.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                username: usernameFromToken,
                name: request.params.name
            },
            {
                $push: {
                    pairs: { code, site }
                }
            }
        )

        const specific = await Redirect.findOne(
            {
                username: usernameFromToken,
                name: request.params.name
            })

        response.send(specific)
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(400).json(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue in my code laid in the fact that I was using a `forEach` look to traverse the `pair` objects within my document's array.**

Since I'm using an `async` function for my `POST` route, I did some searching and found that **`forEach` does not play well within an `async` function.** I switched to using an oldschool `for (let i = 0;` loop and it now works fine!

Here's my code.

1. Get the document and check the `pairs` array
2. If `pairs` contains an object that has the requested code, return an error message.
3. If not, add the `pair` object to the document.

```
// Add pair to given redirect
router.post('/:name/insert_pair', verifyToken, async (request, response) => {
    const token = request.header("auth-token")
    const usernameFromToken = jwt.decode(token).username

    const { code, site } = request.body

    // Remember: you may edit only your own content
    try {
        // Get the object as plain JSON and check if it contains the code
        const check = await Redirect.findOne(
            {
                username: usernameFromToken,
                name: request.params.name
            }
        ).lean()

        // SOLUTION: DON'T USE FOREACH WITHIN ASYNC!
        for (let i = 0; i < check.pairs.length; i++) {
            if (check.pairs[i].code === code) {
                return response.status(400).json({
                    message: `${request.params.name} already contains an entry for ${code}`
                })
            }
        }

        // TODO BUG: ONLY WORKS AFTER 1 DUPLICATE HAS ALREADY BEEN MADE.
        // await check.pairs.forEach((pair) => {
        //     if (pair.code === code) {
        //         return response.status(400).json({
        //             message: `${request.params.name} already contains an entry for ${code}`
        //         })
        //     }
        // })

        // Make the edit
        await Redirect.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                username: usernameFromToken,
                name: request.params.name
            },
            {
                $push: {
                    pairs: { code, site }
                }
            }
        )

        // Get it to display it on screen
        const display = await Redirect.findOne(
            {
                username: usernameFromToken,
                name: request.params.name
            })

        response.json(display)
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(400).json(error)
    }
})
```